# Publish a Blazor Server via Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a solution build with .NET6. The solution is quite basic:

- DashboardUI.Server is the ASP.NET Core hosted project
- DashbaordUI.Client is the Blazor application
- DashboardUI.Shared

I want to deploy this project in an Azure Web App. So, I also create a Release to publish the application in Azure in a Web App.

I have created the pipeline in Azure Devops copying one I use for deploying a Blazor Web Assembly project

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use dotnet 6'
  inputs:
    version: '6.0.x'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/DashboardUI.Server.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/DashboardUI.Server.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: '**/DashboardUI.Server.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The pipeline creates 2 zip files, one for the Server and one for the Client although I explicitly say `projects: '**/DashboardUI.Server.csproj'`. When I run the **Release**, it fails because there is more than 1 project.

When I open the pipeline log, under `Publish`, I see that the pipeline builds both projects and creates 2 zip files.

[image]

How can I fix it and build only the Server project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change publishWebProjects to false